# Using a different column name for a Laravel model property

Tags: php, laravel

I have a Laravel Model, which has a `foo` property. However, in the database, the value that I want to pass into `foo` is stored in the `bar` column.
Is there any way I could do that without changing the database structure? It's owned by a third party which I'm integrating the project with, and I don't really have control over their DB structure.

I've managed to establish a connection to said database using `$connection` and `$table`, but mapping the properties is still remaining an issue.

Comment: Why not having the Model adapted to `bar` property? If thats an issue maybe you want to look at eloquent mutators

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could create a [mutator](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-mutators) for this:

```
public function setFooAttribute($foo)
{
    $this->attributes['bar'] = $foo;
}
```

The `Foo` part of the method name refers to the attribute on the model and then inside the method we're setting the `bar` attribute for the query.